# Boot issues with 64gb sd card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, boot-issues

I just got a raspberry pi 2 B and installed raspbain via noobs as per the [setup guide](http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/) on a 16gb Kingston micro SDHC 8GB class 10 card and everything was working fine and I used it for a day. Then I got a [Sony micro SDXC 64GB class 10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E1XI94Q) card and did the same exact thing as with the 8gb and put it into my pi and booted it up. Nothing happened on my monitor (HDMI) and the green light did not light up. It seems to me that the pi is not not seeing the 64gb card but it is brand new. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After much hair pulling and head banging I realized that windows is unable to format an SD card FAT so it formats it exFAT. I just the raspberry pi can not use exFAT so I used [this](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?fat32format.htm) to format it FAT and then everything worked like usual.

I also had to follow [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/170794/ask-htg-how-can-i-reclaim-the-full-capacity-of-an-sd-card/) to make the card actually one partition instead of one really small and one really big then I made it fat

Comment: did you make 64GB card work for you? I cannot. Formatting entire 64GB card into Fat32 (using 3rd party windows tools )did not work. Creating small Fat32 partition did not work (rest EXT4). Did it work for you? If so, what brand did you use?